# Add field with grok if match classpath

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Could be possible to add field based on specific part of classpath when filebeat send to logstash

Here is the message :

```
2019-10-30 12:30:01,185 DEBUG com.company.class1.json                           - Connection[/10.0.0.31:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
```

I'm trying to filter everything which start with com.company 
and to create special new field but with the whole name of the 
classpath which can be different everytime, could be possible that to be performed dynamically
something like:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:com.company}" }
    }

    if "com.company" in [message]{
        mutate {
            add_field => { "%{here to put com.company.class1.json}" => "12345" }
            convert => { "com.company.class1.json" => "integer" }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually that helps:
in patterns/grok-patterns
add
`JAVACLASS ([\p{Letter}_$][\p{Letter}\p{Number}_$]*\.)*[\p{Letter}_$][\p{Letter}\p{Number}_$]*`
        match => { "message" => "%{JAVACLASS:javaclass}" }

Comment: Have you tried using [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html#using-conditionals)? Like `if [message] =~ /com.company/ { do things}`?